# String characters misinterpreted when iterating over string with unicode chars

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding

I am running on python 2.7 on mac os x 10.6 with file in utf8 and terminal in utf8.

I want to add a period after each occurrence of the vowels å,ä or ö that exist in a given string.

Here is the dumbed down version of what I am trying to do:

```
# coding: utf8

a = 'change these letters äöå'

b = map( (lambda x: a.replace(x, "{0}.".format(x))), 'åäö')

for c in b:
    print c
```

which procudes the following output:

```
change these letters ?.??.??.?
change these letters äöå.
change these letters ?.??.??.?
change these letters ä.öå
change these letters ?.??.??.?
change these letters äö.å
```

Why do I get the lines with the question mark? Upon further research just doing this would produce the same question marks.

```
# coding: utf8

for letter in 'åäö':
    print letter
```

output:

```
?
?
?
?
?
?
```

But explicitly adding the u before gives the

```
# coding: utf8
for letter in u'åäö':
    print letter
```

output:

```
å
ä
ö
```

Decoding and encoding back the string explicitly to `utf8` still produces the question marks. What is the problem here? What is happing in this loop?

*Side note*: In the dumb example you see what I am trying to do. In actuality I am using an object that saves the string so that the mapped operations occur on the same string. So the `map()` call actually calls the object's method with one new vowel each time, thus updating the string saved in the object. The object's method performs the replace with a vowel from the second argument of `map` and updates the stored string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mapping the anonymous function over a string; you should be mapping it over a list of strings.  The Python interpreter will still accept the instruction you're giving it, treating the string as a sequence and applying the lambda to each component of that sequence.   But in that case the components are the individual *bytes* of the string, and each of the unicode characters is two bytes.  So the replacement is performed six times.

Moreover, in three of those iterations the replacement is the identical operation of replacing the unicode prefix byte `0xc3` (which occurs three times in `äöå`), with `0xc3.`, which breaks the character encoding in the string `a` and produces raw byte gibberish.  In the other three iterations you replace the second byte of a unicode char with that byte followed by a period, so the resulting string still contains a byte sequence for the character in question and you get your desired result.  But that's *not* because you're replacing the entire character with that character followed by a period.

Compare:

```
>>> a = 'change these letters äöå'
>>> b = map( (lambda x: a.replace(x, "{0}.".format(x))), 'å ä ö'.split())
>>> for c in b:
...   print c
... 
change these letters äöå.
change these letters ä.öå
change these letters äö.å
```

Comment: The only thing I didn't try this, a list containing each vowel separately. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over the bytes in a bytestring. Since non-ASCII characters encoded as UTF-8 use multiple bytes, you're breaking the characters. If you must iterate over characters then iterate over the characters of a `unicode`.

Comment: This is the option I turned to eventually seeing as functions like lower() did not work on certain unicode characters...